# .NET MAUI Error: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RunetimeIdentifier 'ios-arm64'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, maui

I have a Blazor Server project and a WebApi project that i want to add into a .NET MAUI project.
All are in .NET 6. However, i get this error message when i build the solution.

```
Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'ios-arm64'.   MobileApp   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets   430
```

When I remove the project reference from MAUI to the Blazor and WebApi projects I dont have this issue.

I suppose that there is a reference to these packages that is causing the issue:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Font.Awesome" Version="5.15.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="jose-jwt" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.8" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.8" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.8">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETCore.MailKit" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="papercut" Version="2010.3.3.20130622" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="7.0.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.2.0" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client" Version="6.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.ApiDescription.Client" Version="13.16.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; 
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Font.Awesome" Version="5.15.4" />
```

I use a class library project called SharedLib that includes the WebApi and Blazor Server projects references, then in the MAUI project i reference the sharedLib project.
Then i would like to in the Pages / Index.razor access the Blazor Server Component.

Comment: According to [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/974223/runtime-pack-for-microsoftaspnetcoreapp-available.html), if a package doesn't support, this error will appear.